# How to resize bulk images without uploading on server?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, image-processing

I am trying to build a web tool to resize bulk images. But, uploading to server is taking too much time. Is there any way, I can do the resizing in the browser itself or anything else?

I found a website which does the resizing in the browser.
https://bulkresizephotos.com/en

Is there any idea what is the logic behind this?

Comment: You can have a look at how [compressor.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs) does it or even use it for your task.

Comment: https://codepen.io/warrenkc/pen/vYxdXzr Here is a sample for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) in order to load images locally and draw them in a specific size on your canvas. After that you can load the canvas into a new image using [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).